# Generating the "Issue report" for C# project using SonarLint

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

I’m trying to explore the SonarQube options for C# projects  and in the way I have tried using Sonar Scanner for MSBuild and SonarLint for Visual Studio, But when I’m trying to generate the “issue report” using the issue report plugin it is showing that this plugin as deprecated and suggests to use SonarLint CLI. I tried using the SonarLint CLI for generating the Issue report for C# project, but no report has been generated. But when I have gone through the blogs I came to know that C# is not supported for SonarLint CLI, is it is correct, if yes, Please help me out if there are any other ways to generate the "Issue report" for C# projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin is [deprecated](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Issues+Report+Plugin) since SonarQube 5.1. You could use the [SonarQube Web API](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+API) to build your own report.